# How to improve performance of SQL in Oracle that loads only Items modified during last 5 days?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I have a table M that has CREATED_AT and MODIFIED_AT columns(Date), and this table is very big.
I need to get rows modified or created during last 5 days:

```
Select * from M where MODIFIED_AT >= trunc(sysdate)-5 OR CREATED_AT >= trunc(sysdate)-5
```

There is no index for them, and I am afraid that Oracle will do full scan and it will be slow. What kind of index can be created to improve that?

MODIFIED_AT is Nullable, CREATED_AT is Not-Null.
Is it better to create one index including both columns, or 2 indexes for each column separately?

UPDATE
There is one more thing: some of you suggested to create function based index coalesce(modified_at, created_at), the thing is that items in that table are modified very seldom, but usually created in big chunks(created by system, modified if needed by users). So there can be lots of items with the same created_at and null modified_at. But still there will be some items with modified_at not null. Does it make sense to create a bitmap index? Or any other way to use this fact that created_at will be the same for big chunks of items in table M?

And also, does it make any difference to make the index ASC or DESC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using `union all`:

```
select m.*
from m
where CREATED_AT >= trunc(sysdate) - 5
union all
select m.*
from m
where MODIFIED_AT >= trunc(sysdate) - 5 and CREATED_AT <  trunc(sysdate) - 5;
```

This can then take advantage of indexes on `m(created_at)` and `m(modified_at, created_at)`.

A simple method might be to ensure that `modified_at` is set when the record is created.  Then you could just do:

```
select m.*
from m
where MODIFIED_AT >= trunc(sysdate) - 5 ;
```

Or another alternative would be:

```
select m.*
from m
where greatest(MODIFIED_AT, created_at) >= trunc(sysdate) - 5 ;
```

with a function-based index on `m( greatest(MODIFIED_AT, created_at) )`.  This assumes that neither column is ever `NULL`.

Comment: What kind of index would you recommend to create for these columns? And why can't i avoid union all? Sorry for stupid question, but i have very little experience with indexes.

Comment: and why "CREATED_AT <  trunc(sysdate) - 5" in the second part of union?

Comment: thank you for your comment. modified_at is nullable, and it is important to keep it Null if there are no modifications after creation, we rely on that in other queries. We can't do that change

Comment: Is it better to create one index for all 2 columns, or 2 indexes for each column separately?

Comment: i just checked, and greatest(MODIFIED_AT, created_at) returns Null if MODIFIED_AT is Null :(

Comment: @Alexander: You can address that issue by using `greatest(coalesce(modified_at, created_at), created_at)`. That's assuming that `created_at` can't be `null`. I'd even say, that if you only have natural cases, (so a record can't be updated/modified prior to its creation), you can simply use `coalesce(modified_at, created_at)`, an index based on this expression and use this exact expression in the query filter (`coalesce(modified_at, created_at) >= trunc(sysdate) - 5`).

Comment: There is one more thing: items in that table are modified very seldom, but usually created in big chunks(created by system, modified if needed by users). So there can be lots of items with the same created_at and null modified_at. But still there will be some items with modified_at not null. Does it make sense to create a bitmap index like trunc(coalesce(modified_at, created_at))?

Comment: And also, does it make difference to make the index ASC or DESC? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Alexander . . . The direction of the index can matter in some cases.  I don't think it makes a difference in this case.  Bitmap indexes don't work with inequalities.

Comment: thanks a lot. i see now that 2 separate indexes work well on Oracle 12c